# Book recommendations needed - building foundational knowledge for ISL - Introduction to Statistical Learning (by Gareth James)

Tags: mathematical-statistics, references, calculus, knowledge-discovery

I'm trying to build a data science base from scratch. I started a book called Introduction to Statistical Learning by Gareth James and found that there are many mathematical & statistical concepts that I'm unfamiliar with. I want to bridge this gap in my knowledge. Please recommend some books that will help me do that. (I prefer books over video lectures but if there is some course, that would help, mention that as well.)

Comment: Highly recommend https://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Notation-Guide-Engineers-Scientists/dp/1466230525 as a guide to notation - it will help while reading other resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Mathematics:

1. James Stewart's Calculus

For Statistics:

1. Basic Business Statistics (7e) - Beenson, Levine, Szabat, ...